# Целочисленное деление возвращает тип float

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, float

В коде, в выделенной процедуре(24 строки), нужно полученную дату в формате *unixtime* преобразовать в целое число - определённый час по расписанию.

```
def post(date):  # date = 1637855378
    ...
    post_date = (date % hours(24)) // hours() # hours(t)=t*3600
    ...
    print(f'{post_date + 3}:00, {type(post_date)}')
```

Иногда возвращает тип **float**, но в основном **int**

```
>>> 15.0:00, <class 'float'>
```

Троеточие - то, что не влияет на результат.
Я конечно понимаю, что это можно исправить через `int(post_date)`, но хочу разобраться в ошибке.
Код работает онлайн на Heroku(возможно у них там какие-то проблемы, но я очень сомневаюсь) такая "ошибка" начала выходить пару дней назад(23 ноября, но могло и раньше).

Comment: Не хватает определения функции `hours`.

Comment: Roman Konoval, сама функция есть, я про неё написал в комментарии, и вообще, без неё бы ничего не работало.

Comment: К вам `date` иногда приходит типа `float`, просачивается через всю арифметику и получается `float` на выходе.

Comment: `100000 % (24 * 3600) // 3600` -> `3`. `100000.0 % (24 * 3600) // 3600` -> `3.0`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я не думал, что ```//``` не будет возвращать целое число от работы с float

Comment: Для ответа на вопрос не хватает определения функции `hours`. Не ясно, что она вернет, если не передавать параметры. Если нецелое, то будет такая проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `//` при работе с целыми числами **int** возвращает **int**, а при работе с **float** возвращает **float**